# Unable to resolve service for type 'ICropService' while attempting to activate 'CropsController'?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor-webassembly

So I've been learning Blazor and I started with making a ASP.NET Core hosted wasm with an API and a MSSQL database. For some reason I get this error message:

> "Unable to resolve service for type 'BlazorCoreApp.Server.Services.ICropService' while attempting to activate 'BlazorCoreApp.Server.Controllers.CropsController'".

I've added the interface and service to the configuration but I still can't get it to work.
Am I doing something wrong or did I forget something?

Below is my code:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer("Server=ServerName;Database=DatabaseName;User=Username;Password=******;"));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
```

CropsController.cs

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CropsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICropService _cropService;

        public CropsController(ICropService cropService)
        {
            _cropService = cropService;
        }

        //ActionResult<IEnumerable<Crop>>
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Crop>> GetCrops()
        {
            return await _cropService.GetCrops();

        }
    }
```

ICropService.cs

```
namespace BlazorCoreApp.Server.Services
{
public interface ICropService
    {
        Task<Crop> GetCrops();
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer("Server=mercado-stage.database.windows.net;Database=Mercado_Blazor;User=MercadoStageDbUser;Password=gOyn0V1joQ99;"));

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICropService, CropService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DbContext, DataContext>();


var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @HenkHolterman but no I only have one definition of this interface, I'll update the code so  you can see

Comment: OK, that is the one from the error message. Is it also the type used in   `services.AddScoped<ICropService, CropService>();` ?  Verify, don't assume.

Comment: Can you add the code for the implementation of ICropService? You can omit function body.

Comment: So what does `CropService` look like?  The message suggests `CropService` doesn't conform with the `ICropService` interface definition.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments but I've managed to resolve the issue. I have a Program.cs which uses the Startup.cs to add scopes to the services. I simply moved the `services.AddScoped<ICropService, CropService>(); services.AddTransient<DbContext, DataContext>();` from Program.cs to Startup.cs and it worked fine. I added the Program.cs and updated the Startup.cs so you can see my current solution.